# FB.API Facebook Open Graph returns empty data for user likes for some users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-fql

I have a page in which when the app is permitted by a user, it will list down the user's page likes, and checks whether the user liked my certain facebook page and is a member of that facebook page (in a way both are similar), using FB.API

The problem is that certain users are not returning any data at all, regardless of OS or browser. I already set the 'user_likes' permission on the app, but to no avail.

```
    <html> 
<head> 
<title>My Facebook Login Page</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="fb-root"></div> 
    <div id="lblName"></div> 
    <div id="lblAccessToken" style="display: none;"></div> 
    <br><br> 
    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Your Page Likes</legend> 
        <div id="lblLikes"></div> 
    </fieldset> 

    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Check whether you like [My Fan Page] </legend> 
        <div id="lblYouLike"></div> 
    </fieldset> 

    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Check whether you are a fan of [My Fan Page]</legend> 
        <div id="lblMem"></div> 
    </fieldset> 
    <div id="divLogin" style="display:none;"> 
    <div class="fb-login-button">Login with [App]</div> 
</div> 
<script> 
    var accessToken; 
    var uid; 
    var lblName = document.getElementById("lblName") 
    var divLogin = document.getElementById("divLogin") 
    var lblAccessToken = document.getElementById("lblAccessToken") 
    var lblLikes = document.getElementById("lblLikes") 
    var lblYouLike = document.getElementById("lblYouLike") 
    var lblMem = document.getElementById("lblMem") 

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () { 
        FB.init({ 
            appId: 'APP_ID', // App ID 
            channelUrl : 'http://www.example.com/testing/channel.html', // Channel File 
            status: true, // check login status 
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session 
            xfbml: true // parse XFBML 
        }); 

        FB.getLoginStatus( 
            function (response) { 
                checkStatus(response) 
            } 
        ); 

        FB.Event.subscribe( 
            'auth.authResponseChange', 
            function (response) { 
                checkStatus(response) 
            } 
        ); 

        FB.Event.subscribe( 
            'edge.create', 
            function (response) { 
                //alert('You liked the URL: ' + response); 
                ufCheckLike() 
            } 
        ); 
    }; 

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously 
    ( 
        function(d){ 
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;} 
            js = d.createElement('script'); 
            js.id = id; 
            js.async = true; 
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"; 
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref); 
        } (document) 
    ); 

    function checkStatus(response){ 
        if (response.status === 'connected') { 
            uid = response.authResponse.userID; 
            accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken; 

            lblAccessToken.innerHTML = accessToken; 

            FB.api( 
                '/me', 
                'get', 
                function(response) { 
                    lblName.innerHTML = response.name; 
                } 
            ); 

            divLogin.style.display = "none"; 

            ufCheckLike() 
        } 
        else { 
            divLogin.style.display = ""; 
        } 
    } 

    function ufCheckLike() { 
        if (isLoggedIn()) { 
            FB.api( 
                '/me/likes?' + 
                'access_token=' + accessToken, 
                'get', 
                    function(likes) { 
                        if (likes) { 
                            if (likes.data && likes.data.length > 0) { 

                                for (var i = 0; i < likes.data.length; i++) { 
                                    var like_detail = likes.data[i] 
                                    var lsHTML = like_detail.name + " : " + like_detail.id + "<br>" 
                                    if(like_detail.id == "<PAGE_ID>") 
                                        lblLikes.innerHTML = lsHTML + lblLikes.innerHTML 
                                    else 
                                        lblLikes.innerHTML += lsHTML 
                                } 

                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
            ); 

            FB.api( 
                '/me/likes/<PAGE_ID>?' + 
                'access_token=' + accessToken, 
                'get', 
                function(likes) { 
                    if (likes) { 
                        if (likes.data && likes.data.length > 0) { 
                            lblYouLike.innerHTML = "You Like [Fan Page]!" 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            ); 

            FB.api( 
                '/<PAGE_ID>/members/' + uid + '?' + 
                'access_token=' + accessToken, 
                'get', 
                function(likes) { 
                    if (likes) { 
                        if (likes.data && likes.data.length > 0) { 
                            lblMem.innerHTML = "You are a fan of [Fan Page]!" 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            ); 

        } 

    } 

    function isLoggedIn() { 
        if (!accessToken) { 
            divLogin.style.display = ""; 
            return false; 
        } 
        return true; 
    } 
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I also implemented an FQL which practically does the same thing to check whether a user has liked my page and the same scenario is happening on certain users where data object returns empty rows.

```
var query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan  where uid=me() and page_id = PAGE_ID ' + 'and access_token = " + accessToken;
//Access token is optional
var names = FB.Data.query(query);
names.wait(
    function (rows) {
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            // liked, do codes here
        }
        else {
            // not yet liked, show like button
        }
    }
);
```

I have applied some of the suggestions found here and the script still doesn't work for some users. I am out of clue what particular account/privacy/app setting should be modified to allow querying of the user's page likes, apart from setting the 'user_likes' in the App's user and friend permissions settings.

Comment: Did you try using the Firebug console to check out for whats going wrong with the script?

Comment: Are there any errors popping out in the Console?

Comment: There were no errors logged at all. The thing is, the code could obviously get the user's name, but when it comes to the likes it just doesn't return any value.

Comment: oops, definitely no errors at all since I'm using an account that was able to check it's page likes. I may need to get hold of my friend's account later as his account is experiencing this scenario.

Comment: Have to tried using the Graph API Explorer to make sure there is indeed an issue?  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Silly question, but you're sure the user has likes, right?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure they have likes, and in particular, has liked a certain page I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

You've given no indication how often this is happening so i'm assuming

- It's rare
- You're only ever asking about the current user, not their friends.

If so, some users don't actually have any likes, so this can easily happen and shouldn't be a problem.

If you can verify the user DOES have likes, and has authorised your app with user_likes permission, file a bug in [Facebook's bug tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) and include the user IDs, page IDs, access tokens etc

Comment: Actually, I have two users that I have contact with having this problem, and at least 60 more user reports on our end having problem with our module that uses this code to check the user's like after accepting our app. I am yet to confirm whether they have authorized my app with 'user_likes'. Though, how do you disallow this in the first place? isn't it when you are prompted with the oauth dialog you will either opt in to what the app requires of your data when you accept right?

Comment: I have already tried the Explorer. Application is set to my app, with access token selected 'user_likes'. then using Graph API, get method, https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/likes/<page_id>, no data is returned. Does this mean the user has not permitted 'user_likes' correct?

Comment: But I am puzzled as to how would this be disallowed, which goes back to my first question in this comment thread. The 'user_likes' is already applied to the app.

Comment: no `/me/permissions` checks if they've granted permission, `/<user>/likes/<page>` lets you know if they like that page

Comment: I see. I tried with that user and I only got installed: 1, but no user_likes: 1. I let him access this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/<my_app_id>/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpermissions with his account logged on.

Comment: This returns back to my previous question, how come even if my app has set user_likes on app center settings, it still didn't allow it to read this user's like data?

Comment: separate issue - if you're sure they authorised your app via the app center and not via another method file a bug report with repro steps

Comment: Hi Igy, noob question. the permissions is set on the "authenticated referrals" under auth dialog, or in the "permissions" on the app center?

Comment: They control different AUth flows, you probably want them to be set to the same thing

Comment: I definitely set those two fields with 'user_likes'. then next question, before I move to reporting this issue, does an app needed to be approved by Facebook? This approval is for the open graph actions only, right?

Comment: I think I solved it. My app is for a website, and since the auth dialog is launched with <div class="fb-login-button">, you need to add in scope="user_likes" on the login button! Ack! :) thanks anyway for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be related to this reproducable bug:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/106991419491608
Read my post there for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a detailed solution to a similar issue I faced with the JS api in this post:
[Why is the Facebook API returning an empty array for albums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590501/why-is-the-facebook-api-returning-an-empty-array-for-albums)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(jQuery.type(response.data[i].location) == 'object' )
```

Comment: You should include more details as to how this code snippet actually solved the original answer.